# Adding UWP Code to a Xamarin Forms project, limiting duplication?

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp

I have a UWP Project which is my admin application. It uses MVVM.

I also have a Xamarin Forms project in a separate solution for my drivers. This also uses MVVM. A lot of code is the same in the UWP project as the Xamarin forms project, i.e. the code under my models folder, my helpers folder, and my services.

The differences are with the views and viewmodels.

Does anyone know how I might be able to use the code in my UWP project in the Xamarin forms project? I don't really like duplicating the code across the projects...

Comment: put any common code in a shared library project that both apps can utilize

Comment: thanks Jason, class library seems to target .net 5 but Xamarin code seems to only target .net standard 2.1

Comment: you can create a .NET Standard library targeting any version

Comment: can you actually create a class library with .net standard though? In VS my only options are .net core 1-3 and .net 5.

Comment: Obviously because of the incompatibility i get the following issue: `Project ClassLibrary1 is not compatible with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). Project ClassLibrary1 supports: net5.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0) TestApp epos\TestApp\TestApp\TestApp\TestApp.csproj`

Comment: nvm it's a long day and i was being stupid, had my class library options set to UWP... *sighs*

Comment: VS Mac has templates for ".NET Standard Library", I assume VS2019 does too.

Comment: It does. I realised though, in my UWP project, there's a XXX.Core project which I didn't bother looking at which is essentially a class library targeting .net standard 2.1. Should be perfect for using in the Xamarin Forms project :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anyone know how I might be able to use the code in my UWP project in the Xamarin forms project?

No, there is not such tool could port UWP code to Xamarin Form directly, you need also copy code and write specific logic manually. They use different xaml layout control and available assembly.

And if your Forms UWP client part is similar as admin application, you could add it into Xamarin Forms solution, and render it without forms part. (disable LoadApplication method)

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

  //  LoadApplication(new XamarinTest1.App());
}
```

Add a UWP Project to Your Existing Xamarin.Forms App. please refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2016/connect/xamarin-xamarin-and-the-universal-windows-platform#add-a-uwp-project-to-your-existing-xamarinforms-app).

Comment: Thanks Nico - question though, how would I be able to test the admin side and the client side? Would I have to comment in the loading code?

Comment: I check above comments, it looks you found the solution that porting code to .net standard 2.1 class, right ?